# Is there a matrix_element_inv in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

In Maxima, we have `matrix_element_add`, `matrix_element_mult` and `matrix_element_transpose`.

Is there a `matrix_element_inv`, and if not, how could I make one?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invert matrix,first remember that not all matrix can be inverted, so first be sure that your matrix can be inverted.

For maxima working with matrix the operator for multiplying is .

so with A . A = A^2

if we want to get this value is A^^2

Normally the operator apply to each element of the matrix so if you would to invert all the elements:

```
(%i1) A: matrix ([17, 3], [-8, 11]);

                                  [ 17   3  ]
(%o1)                             [         ]
                                  [ - 8  11 ]



(%i9) A^-1;
                                  [ 1    1  ]
                                  [ --   -  ]
                                  [ 17   3  ]
(%o9)                             [         ]
                                  [   1  1  ]
                                  [ - -  -- ]
                                  [   8  11 ]
```

then to get the inverse of a matrix:

```
(%i2) B: A^^-1;

                                [ 11      3  ]
                                [ ---  - --- ]
                                [ 211    211 ]
(%o2)                           [            ]
                                [  8    17   ]
                                [ ---   ---  ]
                                [ 211   211  ]

(%i4) B.A;

                                   [ 1  0 ]
(%o4)                              [      ]
                                   [ 0  1 ]

(%i5) A.B;

                                   [ 1  0 ]
(%o5)                              [      ]
                                   [ 0  1 ]
```

be sure that your matrix is invertible:

```
(%i6)  Bad: matrix ([2, 3], [4, 6]);

                                   [ 2  3 ]
(%o6)                              [      ]
                                   [ 4  6 ]
(%i7) Bad^^-1;

expt: undefined: 0 to a negative exponent.
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);

(%i8) newdet(Bad);

(%o8)/R/                               0
```

Now you should read carefully this section:
http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_23.html

specially when telling about

```
matrix_element_add
```

so really there are only this opereators so doesn't exist a matrix_element_inv

so you can write your own using lambda functions as follows for example for getting the transpose of all the inverted elements:

```
(%i10) matrix_element_transpose: lambda ([x], x^-1)$

(%i11) transpose(A);
                                  [ 1     1 ]
                                  [ --  - - ]
                                  [ 17    8 ]
(%o11)                            [         ]
                                  [ 1   1   ]
                                  [ -   --  ]
                                  [ 3   11  ]
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It did not help at all.

Comment: Maybe if can help, if you explain what you want to do, because the matrix_element_inv doesn't exists